# If I mess up the login it will go straight to the else condition, if I login correctly, it will go to both conditions

Tags: java, conditional-statements

If I run this and find a match, it will go to the IF and then also do the Else.
If I do not find a match, will give me the else result 4 times.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
User u1 = new User("Dan", "123", 314.45);
User u2 = new User("Steph", "1234",500);
User u3 = new User("Ana", "12345", 314.45);
User u4 = new User("Parsh", "12346",500);
list.add(u1);
list.add(u2);
list.add(u3);
list.add(u4);

System.out.println("Enter user and pass: ");
String userEntered = sc.next();
String passEntered = sc.next();
for(User user: list) {
    if(userEntered.equals(user.getName()) && (passEntered.equals(user.getPassword()))) {
        System.out.println(user);
        System.out.println("Login successfull");  

    } else {
        System.out.println("no se puede");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: impossible. please run on debug, it possible for diff user

Comment: If I pick Dan, it will give:
User [name=Dan, account=314.45]
Login successfull
no se puede
no se puede
no se puede

Comment: add break in success verification

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to stop the loop once the user has logged in. This can be done by adding a `break;` statement at the end of the `if`-block:

```
for(User user: list) {
    if(userEntered.equals(user.getName()) && (passEntered.equals(user.getPassword()))) {
        System.out.println(user);
        System.out.println("Login successfull");  
        break; // stops the loop
    } else {
        System.out.println("no se puede");
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Put the for loop inside a method login()
- Keep the static data ( user details as class fields ), initialize within the constructor.
- The login() method returns true if login is successful, false otherwise.
- Within the for loop, if you find the user, return true.
- Outside the for loop return false.
- Print success / failure based upon the return value of login() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isSuccess` variable for check.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
User u1 = new User("Dan", "123", 314.45);
User u2 = new User("Steph", "1234", 500.0);
User u3 = new User("Ana", "12345", 314.45);
User u4 = new User("Parsh", "12346", 500.0);
list.add(u1);
list.add(u2);
list.add(u3);
list.add(u4);

System.out.println("Enter user and pass: ");
String userEntered = sc.next();
String passEntered = sc.next();
boolean isSuccess = false; 
for (User user : list) {
    if (userEntered.equals(user.getName()) && (passEntered.equals(user.getPassword()))) {
        isSuccess =true;
        break;
    } 
}
if (isSuccess) {
    System.out.println(user);
    System.out.println("Login successfull");

} else {
    System.out.println("no se puede");
}
```

Comment: Omg it's exactly what I needed, thank you all so much, especially Eugen :D

Answer (score 0):

To change your code as little as possible, try this :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
User u1 = new User("Dan", "123", 314.45);
User u2 = new User("Steph", "1234",500);
User u3 = new User("Ana", "12345", 314.45);
User u4 = new User("Parsh", "12346",500);
list.add(u1);
list.add(u2);
list.add(u3);
list.add(u4);

System.out.println("Enter user and pass: ");
String userEntered = sc.next();
String passEntered = sc.next();

User loggedInUser = null; 
for(User user: list) {
    if(userEntered.equals(user.getName()) &&  
        (passEntered.equals(user.getPassword()))) {
    loggedInUser = user;
    break;
}
if (loggedInUser != null) {
    System.out.println(loggedInUser);
    System.out.println("Login successfull");  

} else {
    System.out.println("no se puede");
}
```

However, you should look into Gautam's tips for a cleaner, more scalable solution.

Comment: Similar to Eugens answer, which beat me by a few seconds. But in Eugens answer, there is an error : the user variable is not declared outside of the scope of the for, and is therefore not accessible when he attempts to print it.

Comment: for that I created another tempUser within the scope, it's working now :D